# Am I setting up my methods correctly for the game "Rock, Paper, Scissors"?

Tags: java

I'm creating different methods for my game of rock,paper, scissors.
I'm stuck on how to properly create my "displayRoundResult" & "displayMatchResult" methods. I have no idea what direction to go in.

```
// display round results
private void displayRoundResult(int p1Score, int p2Score)
{
    int winningHand;

    if (winningHand == 1)
    {
        p1Score++;
    }
    if (winningHand == 2)
    {
        p2Score++;
    }
    else if (winningHand == 0)
    {
        p1Score = p1Score;
        p2Score = p2Score;
    }

    //if winning equals ... then p1score goes up by 1 or p2score does
}

 private int winningHand(char player1, char player2)
{   
    int winningHand;
    char R,P,S;

    //tie
    if (player1 == (player2))
    {
        winningHand = 0;
    }

    //if player 1 wins
    if (player1 == R && player2 == S)
    {
        winningHand =  1;
    }
    if (player1 == S || player2 == P )
    {
        winningHand = 1;
    }
    if (player1 == P || player2 == R)
    {
        winningHand = 1;
    }

    //if player 2 wins
    if (player1 == S || player2 == R)
    {
        winningHand = 2;
    }
    if (player1 == P || player2 == S)
    {
        winningHand = 2;
    }
    if (player1 == R || player2 == P)
    {
        winningHand = 2;
    }

    return winningHand;

}
// display match results
private void displayMatchResult(int round, int p1Score, int p2Score)
{
    if (p1Score > p2Score)
    {

    }
}
```

displayRoundResult

I created a method winningHand that determines which player won, and based on that I want this method to add on a point depending on what the winning value is (0 = tie, 1= player 1 won, 2 = player 2 won)

I think this method is fine?

displayMatchResult
I want this method to tell me who won the overall game. So if player 1 has a higher score, then they won the round.

**For this project my teacher gave me these blank methods to fill in. I'm not sure how the int round comes in to play? I'm not asking for answers, just a little guidance please.

Comment: Given the method names, it sounds like you're just supposed to `System.out.println("Player 1 has " + p1Score + " points, Player 2 has " + p2Score);` without trying to modify them

Comment: @thatotherguy oh wow, thank you. I have one more question for you, (if you dont mind). Can you please tell me how to properly call a method? Im going to edit my code & add the method Im referring to(winningHand). Im trying to call that method  into the displayRoundResult, so it can compare properly.